# $ @ % обращение к данным в Perl

Tags: perl

Есть массив

```
@array=('a','b','c');
```

Какая разница, обращусь ли я так

```
print @array[2];
```

или так

```
print $array[2];
```

Такая же ситуация и с хешами.

Answer (score 1):

> Scalar value `@array[2]` better written as `$array[2]` at -e line 1 (#1) (W syntax) You've used an array slice (indicated by @) to select a single element of an array.  Generally it's better to ask for a scalar value (indicated by $).  The difference is that `$foo[&bar]` always behaves like a scalar, both when assigning to it and when evaluating its argument, while `@foo[&bar]` behaves like a list when you assign to it, and provides a list context to its subscript, which can do weird things  if you're expecting only one subscript.
>
> On the other hand, if you were actually hoping to treat the array element as a list, you need to look into how references work, because Perl will not magically convert between scalars and lists for you. See perlref.

[Источник](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=880111).

Comment: Понятно, значит, лучше не рисковать и обращаться через $, спасибо. ))

Comment: Хороший цикл статей есть у Дмитрия Котерова на его сайте: [хэши, массивы и списки в Perl, или уже чуть посложнее][1]. Рекомендую к прочтению, очень все понятно и с богатыми примерами.

Ну и прикупить книжку-верблюжку. Она того стоит.

[1]: http://dklab.ru/chicken/nablas/20.html

Answer (score 1):

Если отвечать коротко и точно на поставленный вопрос, то в данном конкретном случае разницы абсолютно никакой.

А если углубляться в детали, то следует поговорить про значения-скаляры, значения-массивы и про скалярный контекст и контекст массива. print @array[2]; - значение-массив в контексте массива. print $array[2]; - значение-скаляр в контексте массива. Разницы никакой. Разница будет, если попытаться использовать значение-массив в скалярном контексте. Чаще всего это приведет к появлению размера массива.

Попробуйте выполнить и проанализировать такой код:

```
print '01: ', @array[2], "\n";
print '02: ', $array[2], "\n";
print '03: ', @array[1,2], "\n";
print '04: ' . @array[2] . "\n";
print '05: ' . $array[2] . "\n";
print '06: ' . @array[1,2] . "\n";
print '07: ' . join('', @array[1,2]) . "\n";
```

Разница между запятой и точкой в данном случае в том, что при запятой мы передаем функции print набор строк, которые (все по порядку) функция должна вывести на печать, а при точке мы сами собираем (конкатенируем) одну строку, которую затем передаем в функцию print для печати.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $s = @array[2] - не грамотная запись.
my @s = @array[2..4] - нормуль.
my $s = $array[2] - пиши только так!
```

По идее если вначале прописать 'use strict' - то должен ругаться на первую запись (это только по идее - возможно я ошибаюсь)

А вообще 1й символ говорит о там, что возвращает эта запись.